# Difference between using relative elements in selector or chaining querySelector?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

What is the difference between either of these approaches to finding elements that are within other specified elements?

```
// Chaining querySelector()
document.querySelector("#firstDiv").querySelector(".active");
document.querySelector("#firstDiv").querySelectorAll("p");

// Using relative elements
document.querySelector("#firstDiv .active");
document.querySelectorAll("#firstDiv p");
```

Which approach should I be using? Does it matter? If so, why does it matter?

Comment: Why would you even do that? you are querying an element by id, which should be unique on the page.

Comment: I'd imagine a slight performance hit with the first example, but as aximus noted, why?

Comment: In case your question is wrong and you mean querying by class names. I have to agree with j08691

Comment: I see what you mean, and I have rephrased it to use class names. So you think chaining it is worse for performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first approach is error-prone; if `#firstDiv` matches nothing, the first call to `querySelector()` will return null and the following method call will fail with a TypeError.

The second approach, as long as you supply a valid selector, will never throw any errors since you're only dealing with a single call on the document object, which is guaranteed to exist. It will only ever return either the element(s) that match(es) the selector, or null otherwise.

Both approaches are equivalent in that calls to `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` on an element object are treated as descendant (subtree) queries.

Comment: So you would recommend doing something like: `document.querySelector("#firstDiv .active");`?

Comment: @zeckdude: Yes, if you do not need to maintain a reference to #firstDiv. If you *do* need to maintain such a reference, e.g. `var firstDiv = document.getElementById("firstDiv");`, you'll need to null-check it before attempting to use it.

Comment: I think `Element#querySelector` can also match the element it was called on.

Comment: @gcampbell: No, it cannot, not even with :scope or *.

Comment: @BoltClock I was wrong there: the element it's called on can be part of the selector, but not the match. So `document.querySelector("#outer").querySelector("#outer #inner")` works, but joining them into `document.querySelector("#outer #outer #inner")` doesn't work (obviously).