# Mouseenter delegation problems vanilla js

Tags: javascript, delegation

I am trying to create a zoom in function with vanilla Javascript, it works very easy with jquery but with Javascript the mouseenter function triggers multiple times. As result i recieve `<div class="sp-zoom">`... multiple times in my html.

How i can stop it from firing multiple times ?

I tried already a lot of different solutions on StackOverflow but i wasnt able to make this work.

Here a simple example:

```js
document.querySelector('.sp-large').addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
    var largeUrl = document.querySelector('.sp-large').querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
    document.querySelector('.sp-large').innerHTML += '<div class="sp-zoom"><img src="' + largeUrl + '"/></div>';
    document.querySelector('.sp-zoom').style.display = 'block';
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="sp-large"><a href="https://mvz-bietigheim.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/placeholder-image10.jpg" class="sp-current-big"><img src="https://www.bestructural.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/generic-image-placeholder.png" width="600" height="464" alt=""></a></div>
```

On request the working jquery version:

```js
$(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.sp-non-touch .sp-large', function(event) {
  var largeUrl = $('a', this).attr('href');
  $(this).append('<div class="sp-zoom"><img src="' + largeUrl + '"/></div>');
  $(this).find('.sp-zoom').fadeIn(250);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sp-large"><a href="https://mvz-bietigheim.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/placeholder-image10.jpg" class="sp-current-big"><img src="https://www.bestructural.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/generic-image-placeholder.png" width="600" height="464" alt=""></a></div>
```

Comment: My guess is that changing the `innerHTML` somehow retriggers the `mouseenter` Event.

Comment: Is the problem that you're getting mouseenter events from other elements bubbling up? Do you need to check the target of the event and discard those with the wrong target?

Comment: Can you show the working jQuery version, because the logic you have used above doesn't make much sense.   Your doing a mousenter on `.sp-large` and then adding your zoomed into the same div, so because of event bubbling it becomes infinite.

Comment: current code does not check if there is a zoom div already, and adds new one at each mouseenter.
maybe you need to have zoom div presented by default but hidden and show on hover? could be done with just css

Comment: @Keith  i have added the jquery code

Comment: Aside, you might want to write `document.querySelector('.sp-large a')` instead of writing it like `document.querySelector('.sp-large').querySelector('a')` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228487/difference-between-using-relative-elements-in-selector-or-chaining-queryselector).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the event handler is added differently in the two cases - in the jquery case you are catching all events, and jquery is throwing away those that aren't related to your selector, in the vanilla case you're adding the handler to an element and catching everything that bubbles through it

Comment: @Wax  yeah true, thanks for pointing out. Im new to vanilla js have used only Jquery for years.

Comment: Your jQuery one is not even using the mouseOver, when you click it's just following the href,..  IOW: take out all the JQuery code in the second snippet, it would be identical.

Comment: @Keith   the jquery code is not written by me, full code here: https://github.com/kthornbloom/Smoothproducts 
Edit: both dont have a click event, just mouseenter (for this example)

Comment: The JQuery one add's the Zoom to the body, your adding to the '.sp-large' in the jQuery version, `document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="sp-zoom"><img src="' + largeUrl + '"/></div>';` would be the equivalent.

Comment: @Keith          no this line `<div class="sp-zoom"><img src="' + largeUrl + '"/></div>` on the jquery code appears directly inside ".sp-large" below the a tag. Maybe he appends it to the body and moves it later on ?

Comment: @Keith          well i found a temporary solution by adding `if(!document.querySelector('.sp-large .sp-zoom')){` inside the eventlistener, but this still cause the listener getting triggered multiple times, maybe cause performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

You have to clear the `<div class="sp-zoom"><img src="' + largeUrl + '"/></div>` on mouse leave - I think this way you can achieve.

Comment: This should be a comment, no answer.

Comment: Sorry! It was my bad